# Why won't my qgraph print as a network visualization in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r

My code works to create a network visualization in an Rscript file [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibqCm.png)but as soon as I move it over to Rmarkdown, it prints the edge matrix instead: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QWpbB.png)

I'm working with the publicly available ECR data. Below is the code that I'm using:

'''

```
#Anxiety model search BIC
anx_mod_bic <- ggm(anx_dim) %>% 
  runmodel() %>% 
  modelsearch(criterion = "BIC")

#extract edge matrix
anx_mat_bic <- anx_mod_bic %>%
  getmatrix("omega")

#visualize network
varnames_anx <- names(anx_dim)
anx_mod_graph_bic <- qgraph(anx_mat_bic, 
                        layout = "spring", 
                        theme = "colorblind",
                        labels = varnames_anx)
```

'''

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you save a plot into an object it is not plotted but only stored in the object. So here, `anx_mod_graph_bic` will contain the plot which you can create with `plot(anx_mod_graph_bic)`, but R won't plot the result. You can just not store the result of `qgraph(...)` or plot the object.